# poisson distribution problem, expected value and variance calculation

Tags: probability, statistics

For a certain section of pine forest, the number Y of diseased trees per acre has a Poisson distribution with mean lambda=10. The disased trees are sprayed with an insecticide at a cost of 3 dollars per tree, plus a fixed overhead cost for equipment rental of 50 dollars. Letting C denote the total spraying cost for a randomly selected acre, find the expected value and variance for C.

isnt the expected value and variance just lambda which is 10 why does the answer says they are E(C)=80 and Var(C)=90?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've pointed out is that the expectation and variance of $Y$ are both $10$.  But, you weren't asked to compute the expectation and variance of $Y$ -- you were asked to compute them for $C$.

Try to start by writing $C$ as a function of $Y$.

Comment: But a strange thing in the conditions is that for a Poisson R.V, mean=variance, and s/he has mean 80 and variance 90, which even seems to allow for values of 80-90=-10 for the cost.

Comment: Find your function for $C$ in terms of $Y$, and try plugging this in to the expression $\text{Var}[C]=\mathbb{E}[C^2]-(\mathbb{E}[C])^2$. The difference comes in in the $\mathbb{E}[C^2]$ term.

Comment: I understand, but I guess then that $C$ is not Poisson, because of the difference, which I find confusing.

Comment: yeah im confused too so its C=53Y?

Comment: Nope. You are spending \$50 no matter what; then, an extra \$3 per tree.  The number of trees is $Y$... so, that means $C=50+3Y$.

Comment: so when i try to find the (50+3Y)^2-80^2 but it doesnt give me 90....

Comment: i think i need to get the probability part which i dont have?

Comment: It might help to note that $10=\text{Var}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[Y^2]-(\mathbb{E}[Y])^2=\mathbb{E}[Y^2]-100$, so that $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=10+100=110$.

Comment: oh damn i got it now......i cant just put Y^2 directly....

Comment: Nope!  It turns out that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$ only for very, very boring random variables.

Comment: thanks for your help, you have always been helpful to us

Comment: @NickPeterson I still didn't get how the variance could end up being 90.

Answer (score 0):

$C = 3Y + 50$ and $Y = (C - 50)/3$ and $E(Y) = 10$ // expectation or mean of a poisson distribution = lambda

$Var(Y) = Var((C-50)/3) = 10$ // variance of a poisson distribution = lambda

$(1/9)Var(C) = 10$ //pull out 1/3, -50 is not relevant

$Var(C) = 90$

$E(X)$ is easy, but can be found by $E((C-50)/3)) = 10$, but it's simply $50 + 3 \times 10$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your posts to make everything easier to read. :)